# How to translate the English expressions "it's up to you" and it's down to you" into German?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, phrase-request

In english the expression "it's up to you" leaves the decision to you. Whereas the expression "it's down to you" leaves the responsibility for an action down to you.

I used Google  translate for both expressions "it's up to you" and "it's down to you" and both results were "Es liegt an dir".

Is it only context that differentiates the meaning of "Es liegt an dir"?

Is there more than one way of expressing these English expressions in to German?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both expressions' translations to German will depend on context. The translation Google Translate gave you will only be appropriate in some contexts.

Depending on context, "it's up to you" may also be translated as:

- "Es ist deine/Ihre Entscheidung."
- "Ganz wie du willst." / "Ganz wie Sie wollen."
- "Mir ist das egal."

"It's down to you" may be translated as:

- "Das ist deine/Ihre Verantwortung."
- "Du bist/Sie sind am Zug."
- "Kümmere du dich darum." / "Kümmern Sie sich darum."
- "Das geht mich nichts an."
- "Das ist nicht mein Problem."

Comment: The latter of each variants would more closely translate to *I don't care*, which is clearly distinct from the addressed person.

Comment: Translating back and forth often doesn't end up on the original. That's a natural consequence of the fact that semantic fields in different language  seldom coincide.

Comment: I would add _Das ist dein Bier_ as an idiomatic version of _it's down to you_.